# How to convert activity code from log curve with mnemonic ACTCOD to string in WITSML 1.3.1?

Tags: xml

I am working with WITSML 1.3.1 and am retrieving activity code values through the Log object. The log curve values with mnemonic ACTCOD contains the activity code but they are specified as numeric values, e.g. 0, 1, 2 ...

How do I convert them into a string representation? Does they map directly to the enumValues.xml as specified by Energistics? If so, does the first string value correspond to the numeric value 0 from the log or 1?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Jay Hollingsworth, Chief Technology Officer of Energistics for his response to my inquiry via email.

Based on his advice, the WITSML standard do not define mnemonic codes and look up values for activity codes. The numeric values that I have encountered in these logs are probably legacy WITS codes for mnemonic codes and are vendor dependent.

Perhaps the better way to obtain activity code information is through the RealTime object.